# JAVA Robot mouseMove 2 Monitors

Tags: java, mousemove, awtrobot

I'm trying to write a program that would bring the mouse cursor to certain coordinates, according to timings, regardless of the user. I wrote a simple code using Robot, but ran into a problem ... I have two monitors, and the cursor moves incorrectly depending on what monitor it is on at the moment, please tell me how to solve the problem.

The code below is what I was trying to create ...

```
    GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

    GraphicsDevice[] graphicsDevices = graphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices();

    for(int i=0; i < graphicsDevices.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(graphicsDevices[i]);            
    }

    try {

        //Robot robot = new Robot(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getDevice());            

        Robot robot = new Robot();            

        while(true)
        {
            robot.mouseMove(-1640, -3);

            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the idea of get the resolution and then move from there. You are doing **ABSOLUTE** moves and they will work different in differents setups.

You should use this code

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

from there you could:

```
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
robot.mouseMove (width-10, height+3);
```

So you would move ***relatively*** to the specs of the monitor. I hope I have helped.